# Set default value for a field while populating POJO using Bean Utils

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons, pojo, apache-commons-beanutils

I am trying to populate the fields of a POJO using `BeanUtilsBean.populate(object, fieldNameVSfieldValueMap)` method.

My POJO looks like :

```
class POJO{
  Integer intField;
  Double doubleField
  String str;
}
```

Currently I have a HashMap that contains a map between the field name and field value.

Now with the following code:

```
POJO obj = new POJO();
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("intField", "1");
map.put("doubleField", "1.1");
BeanUtilsBean.populate(obj, map)
```

With the above code in my POJO object obj, the fields intField and doubleField get populated with the values 1 and 1.1 respectively which is as expected.

The problem with this is that, the string field str get null assigned to it as there was no entry in the hashmap for str and null is default value for String.
But I want was an explicit way to set my custom value to a field when they are not mentioned in the map.
For this example lets say I want to set str to "john" as there is not entry for str in the map. 
Edit 1: 
And also that should be specific to the field type. So if there are other fields in POJO and they are of String type, then for all those String fields, for whom entry is not there in the Map should be populated with John.

Edit 2: The POJO is defined in a different project that I dont have commit access to, so set default values in the POJO itself is not a solution to me.

Comment: well... just set a default value for that string then, `String str = "john";` , otherwise it will be replaced by the value passed in the HashMap

Comment: The pojo is defined in different project that I dont have commit access to so cant reaaly set default values that way. And also I have multiple fields

Comment: ok, add this information to your question because it's very important :)

Comment: fine added :) I somehow thought this could be achieved through org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean, but could not fine helpful thing at their documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean class with aid of the org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean class

Answer (score 2):

Basically you could do:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>() {  // new HashMap<String, String> perhaps
    @Override
    public String get(Object key} {
        return super.getOrDefault(key, "john");
    }
}
```

If you want different defaults per field, use a local map, prefilled with defaults.

Then you should make your own class.

Comment: The way I understand, this will try to set the value to "John" for all the fields that are there in the POJO but not there in the map. Instead I need this thing to be done only for string fields

Comment: @DockYard then you need to discriminate on the field, like using a local map of string field names, maybe determined once per reflection.