# Set default value for all field while populating POJO

Tags: java, javabeans, pojo, apache-commons-beanutils

I want to populate a POJO object in java, with custom default value for all the fields based on the field type.
For example if I have a POJO class,

```
class POJO{
  String str1;
  String str2;
  Integer integ1;
  Integer integ2;
}
```

Now I want a mechanism to populate (say) **"John"** to the string fields and **1** to the Integer fields.

I was trying to use **org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean** and **org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean** for this purpose, but have been unable to.

Please help

Comment: `String str1 = "John"`?

Comment: Use a constructor to populate fields based on your criteria.

Comment: You already asked this few minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336524/set-default-value-for-a-field-while-populating-pojo-using-bean-utils

Comment: You can also set default values in setter methods.

Comment: @Eugene  yeah. String should be "John"